# SVN and Redmine project management integration

Tags: svn, project-management, redmine

Nowadays I am using Redmine to manage my project, and I know some key integrations with svn commit log, such as:

```
refs #1559
```

or

```
resolves #1565
```

Does anyone know where I can find more information about this integration, or where I can configure something like spent time on my commit log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much information about the integration, outside of the [source itself](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/app/models/changeset.rb#L80). Automated time tracking in the commit log is a great idea, but is currently unsupported. There is [an issue](http://www.redmine.org/issues/4155) including [a patch](http://www.redmine.org/attachments/4800/logtime_redmine_1.0.3-v3.patch) that has recently been scheduled for [the 1.1.0 release](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/versions/20). You could apply the patch to your redmine installation and assist the project by reporting your experience with the feature.

Comment: Thank you! I'll start to follow the changes